# Converting ArrayList to Collections.synchronizedList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I know that `ArrayList` is not thread safe and I've seen many people recommending
converting it in `(Collections.synchronizedList)` . I need to create a system where I convert my `ArrayList` to `(Collections.synchronizedList)` and then back to `ArrayList`. But first I need to insert `a` in `b`.

The problem is that I do not know how to convert from `(Collections.synchronizedList)` to `ArrayList` and I get an error when I try to insert the following element:

```
public List<Object> a;
public List<ArrayList<Object>> b;

a = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());
b = Collections.synchronizedList(b);
```

When I try the following command an exception is thrown:

```
b.add(id, (ArrayList<Object>) a);
```

> java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better change the `b` variable to:

```
public List<List<Object>> b;
```

which doesn't depend on a concrete implementation. It will make possible to pass any `List` implementation you want - either an `ArrayList` or a `Collections.SynchronizedList`.

Otherwise, if you don't want to change the field type (I wouldn't recommend doing so), you could use either a copy constructor:

```
b.add(2, new ArrayList<>(a));
```

or a Stream API approach:

```
b.add(2, a.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass b as an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` after I finish inserting in it, and from what I've read it is not possible without manually copying each and every item.

Comment: @nigod, well, it's not a good design solution if you are supposed to pass an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` as a parameter, right?

Comment: I can not change the parameter's type :(

Comment: I changed the whole approach to the problem, I found something more intelligible. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

a) Careful, Collections.synchronizedList() does not make your list entirely thread safe, it just synchronizes your operations. If you have multiple threads reading and writing your list, you may still run into ConcurrentModificationException if you don't know what you are doing. If you want better thread safety, use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). If, for example, one thread adds items to a List, while another iterates, that will break any List implementation except CopyOnWriteArrayList, whether or not it's wrapped in Collections.synchronizedList().

b) Collections.synchronizedList() is a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) around your original list. I.e. your ArrayList is still there, inside the decorator. You don't need to copy it back, just keep a reference to the original ArrayList variable. Every change you made to the synchronized List got propagated to the ArrayList. On the other hand: why do you need an ArrayList? A good api will accept any List type. Relying on ArrayList as implementation type violates at least one [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) rule (Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces). So unless you code against an API that explicitly requires ArrayList, just use your synchronized list (change your field type to `List<List<Object>>`).

Answer (score 1):

There's an `ArrayList` constructor that takes a `Collection`:

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(a);
```

However, it might be more reasonable to change the type of `b` to `List<List<Object>>`:

```
public List<ArrayList<Object>> b;
b.add(id, a);
```

Comment: ok, but then how will I be able to convert b to `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` ?

Comment: @Egor wanted to post the same thing, saw your answer, clicked your profile, same city :) u get un upvote for that

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

It's simple. Your `b` variable is of type:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> b
```

So it contains elements of type `ArrayList<Object>` and not `List<Object>`. Thus the compiler complaints when you try to insert `a` since `a` is not of type `ArrayList<Object>` (it never was though). You have created it by using

```
a = Collections.synchronizedList(...);
```

The method `Collections#synchronizedList` does **not** return an `ArrayList`, it returns a `List`.

---

### Solution

Change your `b` object to

```
List<List<Object>> b
```

and you will be able to insert `a`.

Alternatively you would need to explicitly convert `a` to `ArrayList` again. For example by using.

```
ArrayList<Object> resultA = new ArrayList<>(a);
```

and then inserting `resultA`. The given constructor creates a new `ArrayList` which adds all elements of the given collection.

Comment: but I still need to return b as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`, what should I do? So basically I have a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` intended to be thread-safe and I try some sort of conversions to make that possible.

Comment: @nigod Why do you need that the objects are `ArrayList`? Note that `Collections#synchronizeList` just **wraps** the given list. All accesses will in the end pass the calls of the original list. So if you are interested on `RandomAccess` (which `ArrayList` has) note that the `List` returned by the method will also have `RandomAccess`. Indeed it even implements `RandomAccess` in that case and you can use `list instanceof RandomAccess` to check for that.

Comment: See the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) of this method.

Comment: You won't be able to maintain `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` and also synchronize it. The alternative would be to create a class `SynchronizeManager` which maintains this object internally and all accesses you want to make you do through this class. Then you internally can have this object but all accesses, if done through `SynchronizeManager` could be made synchronized. But honestly, I think the best would be to work on `List<List<Object>>` by using `Collections#synchronizeList`.

Comment: Or are you asking for converting it once to a synchronized version, the doing some heavy computations and after that converting it back? I mean the runtime won't be good since you need to build the resulting structure from ground up (copy everything) but if you only do it once it won't matter that much.